# Select All columns for all tables in join + linq join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How to select all columns from tables in join using linq

Sql:

```
select CTRL_RUN_JOB.*, CTRL_DATA_STREAM.*
 from CTRL_RUN_JOB inner join CTRL_DATA_STREAM
      on CTRL_RUN_JOB.DATA_STREAM_ID= CTRL_DATA_STREAM.DATA_STREAM_ID
```

Linq:

```
from CTLJCRJOB in CTRL_RUN_JOBs 
join CTLRFDSTM in CTRL_DATA_STREAMs 
on CTLJCRJOB.DATA_STREAM_ID equals CTLRFDSTM.DATA_STREAM_ID
select  new {
         CTLJCRJOB.*  // ???
        ,CTLRFDSTM.*  // ???
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

While you cant expand them to columns, you can simply return the entities. Eg:

```
select new { CTLJCRJOB, CTLRFDSTM }
```

If you need it flattened, then you will have to write out the mapping yourself, but will still be very trivial.

Comment: what will be return type of a method who return this type of query result ? and how can i count the number of records of this query results retun

Comment: @rahularyansharma: The return type depends. In your case, it is probably best that you store the results into a list `toList()` and then you can use the `Count` property. Or if you call `Count()` on the query, it will do a `Select Count`.

Comment: You can make a custom class to hold CTLJCRJob and CTLRFDSTM so you do not have to deal with returning an anonymous type.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the into clause, but it will not flatten it for you.

```
from CTLJCRJOB in CTRL_RUN_JOBs 
join CTLRFDSTM in CTRL_DATA_STREAMs 
on CTLJCRJOB.DATA_STREAM_ID equals CTLRFDSTM.DATA_STREAM_ID into ALLCOLUMNS
from entry in ALLCOLUMNS
select entry
```

Answer (score 1):

Another twist is

```
OutPutList = (from CTLJCRJOB in CTRL_RUN_JOBs 
              join CTLRFDSTM in CTRL_DATA_STREAMs 
                on CTLJCRJOB.DATA_STREAM_ID equals CTLRFDSTM.DATA_STREAM_ID
              select CTLJCRJOB).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `into` clause, but it will not flatten it for you.

```
from CTLJCRJOB in CTRL_RUN_JOBs 
join CTLRFDSTM in CTRL_DATA_STREAMs 
on CTLJCRJOB.DATA_STREAM_ID equals 
CTLRFDSTM.DATA_STREAM_ID into ALLCOLUMNS
from entry in ALLCOLUMNS
select entry
```

in this way we can only get `CTLJCRJOB`  columns result, there was no `CTLRFDSTM`  table columns through my test