# How to select all columns in LINQ Datatable join?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                 on t1["id"] equals t2["id"]
                 select new { Name = t1["name"], Group = t2["group"] };
```

I want to select all columns of both table like join in SQL Server inner join query.

In Addition
How can i convert whole result of both tables to data-table?

Comment: You could list all properties you need from 2 tables in `select new {...}`

Answer (score 5):

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
             on t1["id"] equals t2["id"]
             select new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 };
```

then...

**EDIT:**

Something along those lines

```
//clone dt1, copies all the columns to newTable 
DataTable newTable = dt1.Clone();

//copies all the columns from dt2 to newTable 
foreach(var c in dt2.Columns)
    newTable.Columns.Add(c);

//now newTable has all the columns from the original tables combined

//iterates over collection
foreach (var item in collection) {
    //creates newRow from newTable
    DataRow newRow = newTable.NewRow();
    //iterate the columns, gets values from either original table if column name is there
    foreach(var c in newTable.Columns)
        newRow[c.ColumnName] = item.T1.ContainsColumn(c.ColumnName) ?  item.T1[c.ColumnName] : item.T2[c.ColumnName];
    newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

This will work. But if dt1 and dt2 share multiple columns with the exact same name, you might have some loss of data.

Comment: This how i will able to access row one by one. :( i want to convert result to data-table. How can i convert whole result of both tables to data-table?

Comment: Snippet done. I highly recommend you use a less automated version (manually naming each column from the inner join). As I mentioned in the answer, if dt1 and dt2 have columns with the same name, it will only get the value of one of them (dt1) and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't expand them to columns, you can simply return the entities. Eg:

```
select new { CTLJCRJOB, CTLRFDSTM }
```

If you need it flattened, then you will have to write out the mapping yourself, but will still be very trivial.

**Referenced from:**

[Select All columns for all tables in join + linq join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671765/select-all-columns-for-all-tables-in-join-linq-join)

ou have to specify each manually if you want to project into a flattened type. Your other option is to just have your combined type contain both objects, and the objects will naturally bring along their properties.

```
select new 
{
    Object1 = object1,
    Object2 = output
};
```

And you would work with it like myObj.Object1.Property1, myObj.Object2.Property4, etc.

One final option that still involves some manual work is to define an appropriate type and have a constructor or a builder method that does the work of segmenting out your object properties into a flattened type. You still perform the manual mapping, but you isolate it from your query logic.

```
select new CombinedType(object1, output);
//or 
select builder.GetCombinedType(object1, output);
```

**Referenced From**

[Select all columns after JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861059/select-all-columns-after-join-in-linq)

Comment: You should never post a link-only answer as it will be invalid if the URL pasted here is dead. Refer [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake I never knew such protocol exists. I'll edit my answer even though @DesertFox given the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var collection = (from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
>                  join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
>                  on t1  ["id"] equals t2  ["id"]
>                  select new { Name = t1  ["name"], Group = t2  ["group"] }).ToList() ;
> ```

Hope this will help

Comment: My table containing 62 columns. How can i specify columns like this one by one? name, group etctetc

Comment: If you can better to retrieve the data using and SP or a basic query and then manipulate them as an object. I don't think it is a good idea to get all the 62 columns in linq query