# Linq join select all columns and CopyToDataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, datatable

[TABLE SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgkUW.jpg) I'm having trouble solving a query in linq to dataset; I have to make a simple left join between two datatable but I do not know in advance the exact number of columns in the datatable B (A, B, C ...?) so I wanted to select all the columns; I found the following link

[select-all-columns-after-join-in-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861059/select-all-columns-after-join-in-linq)

[select-all-columns-for-all-tables-in-join-linq-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671765/select-all-columns-for-all-tables-in-join-linq-join)

```
        Dim Query = From A In TableA _
                    Join B In TableB _
                    On A("COD") Equals B("COD") _
                    Select New With {A, B}
        Dim TableC As DataTable = Query.CopyToDataTable()
```

I tried also

```
Select New With {.DAT = A.ItemArray.Concat(P.ItemArray).ToArray()}).ToList
```

and many more but i failed to **bring the query result to a new datatable**; I received type conversion errors or i did not understand how to bring the query result provided in two separate tables into one datatable.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the new `datatable` to the two columns `A("COD")` and `B("COD")`?

Comment: nothing, is just for not put in the [Select New With {.....] statement the individual columns to be selected from Table B because i can not determine how many columns are present in table B and i would not use dynamics linq (So I decided to select all the columns indistinctly) see TABLE SCHEMA

Comment: So your TABLE SCHEMA shows column `COD` twice, but that isn't allowed in a `DataTable`.

Comment: true, there is an easy way to avoid repeating the COD column and still have all the remaining columns in Table B tied together without even knowing the name of the column in advance?. On Table B I indicated A B C but it could be L M N O or any other sequence

Answer (score 0):

Creating some extension methods and using Reflection will do what you want, though this may not be the ideal way to solve your issue (generally, Reflection never is).

```
Public Module SomeExt
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function GetTypedValue(Of TProp)(ByVal p As PropertyInfo, obj As Object) As TProp
    Return DirectCast(p.GetValue(obj), TProp)
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function FlattenToDataTable(Of T)(src As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
    Dim ans = New DataTable()

    Dim srcdtpis = GetType(T).GetProperties().Cast(Of PropertyInfo)().ToList()
    For Each aDT As DataTable In srcdtpis.Select(Function(pi) pi.GetTypedValue(Of DataRow)(src.First()).Table)
        For Each col In aDT.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()
            ans.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType)
        Next
    Next

    For Each drs In src
        Dim newDR = ans.NewRow
        For Each aDR In srcdtpis.Select(Function(pi) pi.GetTypedValue(Of DataRow)(drs))
            For Each colname In aDR.Table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().Select(Function(dc) dc.ColumnName)
                newDR(colname) = aDR(colname)
            Next
        Next
        ans.Rows.Add(newDR)
    Next

    Return ans
End Function
End Module
```

You would use it as follows:

```
Dim Query = From A In TableA.AsEnumerable() _
                Join B In TableB.AsEnumerable() _
                On A("COD") Equals B("COD") _
                Select New With {A, B}
Dim TableC As DataTable = Query.FlattenToDataTable()
```

Note that duplicate column names will be set to the last `DataTable`'s value.

Comment: great; when you've also entered how to use the function was the end of a nightmare; the only thing is that throw an error when it try to create the COD column twice; I solved changing the line as follow [If Not (ans.Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName)) Then ans.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType)] . thanks

Comment: I didn't think of the `Add` causing an issue - I modified the datarow assignments so it would just overwrite duplicates.