# Linq into clause returning only columns from joined table

Tags: c#, linq

I joined a 2 data tables based on the EMP column and used copytodatatable, however when i load the new datatable into datagridview it only shows the joined columns(salarydt) from the query, why is this??

```
 var collection = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         join q in salaryDT.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<int>("Emp") equals q.Field<int>("Emp1") into UP
                         from t in UP
                         select t;
 DataTable resultdt = new DataTable();
 dt = collection.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter what can i do to select all the columns from the join? i just wanted to join the salary column to the main datatable based on the EMP number but its giving me so many problems

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671765/select-all-columns-for-all-tables-in-join-linq-join

Comment: Your query only selects `t`. You need to combine the `p` and `t` objects to get the values of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable` itself is perfectly geared to merging itself with another data table, using its, well, `Merge` method. Here's a litte example:

```cs
var dt1 = new DataTable("a");
dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("Item1", typeof(int));
dt1.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt1.Columns[0] };

var dt2 = new DataTable("a");
dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("Item2", typeof(int));
dt2.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt2.Columns[0] };


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, i });
    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, i + 10 });
}

dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

Now `dt1` has three columns, `ID`, `Item1`, and `Item2`.

```cs
ID  Item1   Item2
0   0       10
1   1       11
2   2       12
3   3       13
4   4       14
5   5       15
6   6       16
7   7       17
8   8       18
9   9       19
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is just what i wanted, a simple and short method, however my second datatable contains ID that is not in the first datatable and its returning me an error saying it failed to enable constraint(because C# still adds the unmatching ids into the merged table with null values for all the other columns), so i just looped through the merged table and removed the columns that are null and now it works perfect :)

Comment: Oops meant to say removed rows where there are null values, anyway thanks again i cant believe i didnt explore this merge method after seeing it online while searching for solutions to my problem, spent a frustrating 2 hrs on my problem before asking on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you should to do is just return a custom list of items:

**Option 1**

```
var data = new Employee[] { new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" } };

var data2 = new Salary[] { new Salary { Id = 1, Wage = "$ 50,000.00" } };

var collection = from p in data
                   join q in data2 on p.Id equals q.Id              
                   select new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Wage = q.Wage };
```

Please check the example: [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3GRwR0)

**Option 2**

```
var data = new Employee[] { new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" } };

var data2 = new Salary[] { new Salary { Id = 1, Wage = "$ 50,000.00" } };

var collection = from p in data
                   join q in data2 on p.Id equals q.Id              
                   select new { p, q };
```

Comment: I tried option 1 but i have over 30 columns and its not practical to select all of them manually, and option 2 i tried as well but i cant copy to datatable afterwards

Comment: Looks that there is no shortcut at least based on this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset