# LINQ join "select all" returns only the columns of the second table

Tags: c#, linq

I need a List of objects whose properties will be the columns' names.

This is my approach:

```
var list = (from student in context.Student
        join school in context.School
        on student.idSchool equals school.idSchool
        into allcolumns
        from entry in allcolumns
        select entry).ToList();
```

but list happens to be only a list of `School`s. How can I accomplish my goal? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select All columns for all tables in join + linq join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671765/select-all-columns-for-all-tables-in-join-linq-join)

Comment: Do you have left join or something, to group it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Select Linq expression returns `IEnumerable<T>` The `T` can be anonymous type. In your case, if you want only certain columns, you need to express which ones.

```cs
var mylist = 
    from student in context.Student
    join school in context.School on student.idSchool equals school.idSchool
    select new 
    {
        student.idSchool, // if you want specific name - define >> SchoolId = student.idSchool
        student.Property1,
        student.Property2,
        student.Property3,
        school.Property1,
        school.Property2,
        school.Property3,  
    };
```

Now that you have Enumerable of your anonymous type, you can always call `ToList/ToArray` as needed. Keep in mind, make sure to call it only once and reuse variable because of concept of *"deferred execution"*

Answer (score 1):

I'm checking your linq, I think you can change like this:

```
var mylist = from student in context.Student
    join school in context.School
    on student.idSchool equals school.idSchool
    select new 
    {
      Stud = student,
      Scho = school
    };
```

The variable list will be a Enumerable T, Anonymous type

You could check the result with:

```
foreach(var item in mylist)
{
    Console.Writeline($"{item.Stud.YourFieldName} | {item.Scho.YourFieldName}");
}
```

Best Regards